# Value changing within echo statement

Tags: php, oop

I have the following code (taken from Zend Certification Exercise):

```
<?php
class Magic
{
    public $a = "A";
    protected $b = array("a" => "A", "b" => "B", "c" => "C");
    protected $c = array(1, 2, 3);

    public function __get($v)
    {
        echo "$v,";
        return $this->b[$v];
    }

    public function __set($var, $val)
    {
        echo "$var: $val,";
        $this->$var = $val;
    }
}

$m = new Magic();
echo $m->a ."," .$m->b ."," .$m->c .",";
$m->c = "CC";
echo $m->a ."," .$m->b ."," .$m->c;
```

This outputs the following:

```
b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,C
```

Most of the output I understand, but the first echo statement I don't - how does the output possibly start with anything other than "A"? After all, a is a public property, it is properly defined and therefore __get will not be called, and even if it was called, I still don't understand how it would output "b".

If I change the first echo statement to just:

```
echo $m->a;
```

It outputs:

```
A
```

As expected. So the value is changing within the (full) echo statement, presumably to do with precedence.

Would be really interested in a full explanation of this output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
echo $m->a ."," .$m->b ."," .$m->c .",";
```

can be written also in this way:

```
$text = $m->a ."," .$m->b ."," .$m->c .",";
echo $text;
```

As above, the command behavior is more clear:

**First the string is concatenated, then the concatenated string is printed:**

> ```
> $m->a  =>                             'A,' is added to string
> $m->b  => __get() print 'b,'   then   'B,' is added to string
> $m->c  => __get() print 'c,'   then   'C,' is added to string
> echo   => print 'A,B,C' (concatenated string)
> ```

Comment: The code is from the Zend Certification exercises I am not trying to get a different output, I just want to know WHY the output is as it is

Comment: yes, I know. the explanation is not clear?

Comment: OK so print executes immediately, whereas echo will first concatenate?

Comment: In an _internal_ variable. The command is “echo this string”: so, first the string is concatenated, then is printed.

Comment: Whereas print happens automatically it seems?

Comment: Not exactly. print = echo (there is only `echo` in yr example). The `echo` inside function is a distinct command from the main echo: it is executed before only because it happen when main concatenation is not complete. Main `echo` is performed when string to print out is complete.